# how to integrate a servo in a metal detector?

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-c++, servo

I've been trying to add a servo in to this meta detector I made in such a way that when it detects metal the servo rotates a specified angle stays there for a specified time and returns to its previous position. but since I don't rly know how to code in c++ which I think is what the Arduino Uno board uses I'm clueless. I found the code online and it currently works with an led but I need it to work with a servo as previously stated.

code that uses led

```
/*
 * Metal detector
 * We use the code of this project, 
 * with minor changes:
 * https://www.instructables.com/id/Simple-Arduino-Metal-Detector/
 */
 
const byte npulse = 12; // number of pulses to charge the capacitor before each measurement
 
const byte pin_pulse = A0; // sends pulses to charge the capacitor (can be a digital pin)
const byte pin_cap  = A1; // measures the capacitor charge
const byte pin_LED = 12; // LED that turns on when metal is detected
 
void setup() {
  pinMode(pin_pulse, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(pin_pulse, LOW);
  pinMode(pin_cap, INPUT);
  pinMode(pin_LED, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(pin_LED, LOW);
}
 
const int nmeas = 256; //measurements to take
long int sumsum = 0; //running sum of 64 sums
long int skip = 0; //number of skipped sums
long int diff = 0;      //difference between sum and avgsum
long int flash_period = 0; //period (in ms)
long unsigned int prev_flash = 0; //time stamp of previous flash
 
void loop() {
 
  int minval = 2000;
  int maxval = 0;
 
  //perform measurement
  long unsigned int sum = 0;
  for (int imeas = 0; imeas < nmeas + 2; imeas++) {
    //reset the capacitor
    pinMode(pin_cap, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(pin_cap, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(20);
    pinMode(pin_cap, INPUT);
    //apply pulses
    for (int ipulse = 0; ipulse < npulse; ipulse++) {
      digitalWrite(pin_pulse, HIGH); //takes 3.5 microseconds
      delayMicroseconds(3);
      digitalWrite(pin_pulse, LOW); //takes 3.5 microseconds
      delayMicroseconds(3);
    }
    //read the charge on the capacitor
    int val = analogRead(pin_cap); //takes 13x8=104 microseconds
    minval = min(val, minval);
    maxval = max(val, maxval);
    sum += val;
 
    //determine if LEDs should be on or off
    long unsigned int timestamp = millis();
    byte ledstat = 0;
    if (timestamp < prev_flash +12) {
      if (diff > 0)ledstat = 1;
      if (diff < 0)ledstat = 2;
    }
    if (timestamp > prev_flash + flash_period) {
      if (diff > 0)ledstat = 1;
      if (diff < 0)ledstat = 2;
      prev_flash = timestamp;
    }
    if (flash_period > 1000)ledstat = 0;
 
    //switch the LEDs to this setting
    if (ledstat == 0) {
      digitalWrite(pin_LED, LOW);
    }
    if (ledstat == 1) {
      digitalWrite(pin_LED, LOW);
    }
    if (ledstat == 2) {
      digitalWrite(pin_LED, HIGH);
    }
 
  }
 
  //subtract minimum and maximum value to remove spikes
  sum -= minval; sum -= maxval;
 
  //process
  if (sumsum == 0) sumsum = sum << 6; //set sumsum to expected value
  long int avgsum = (sumsum + 32) >> 6;
  diff = sum - avgsum;
  if (abs(diff)<avgsum >> 10) {   //adjust for small changes
    sumsum = sumsum + sum - avgsum;
    skip = 0;
  } else {
    skip++;
  }
  if (skip > 64) {  // break off in case of prolonged skipping
    sumsum = sum << 6;
    skip = 0;
  }
 
  // one permille change = 2 ticks/s
  if (diff == 0) flash_period = 1000000;
  else flash_period = avgsum / (2 * abs(diff));
}
```

I've tried doing what I saw form yt tutorials but as soon as i try anything it all stops working. it'll be great if you guys can help me as I have an incoming deadline for this project.
heres the code i tried using

```
 /*
   Metal detector
   We use the code of this project,
   with minor changes:
   https://www.instructables.com/id/Simple-Arduino-Metal-Detector/
*/
#include <Servo.h>
Servo servo1;
int servoPin = 9;

const byte npulse = 12; // number of pulses to charge the capacitor before each measurement

const byte pin_pulse = A0; // sends pulses to charge the capacitor (can be a digital pin)
const byte pin_cap  = A1; // measures the capacitor charge
const byte pin_LED = 12; // LED that turns on when metal is detected

void setup() {
  servo1.attach(servoPin);

  pinMode(pin_pulse, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(pin_pulse, LOW);
  pinMode(pin_cap, INPUT);
  pinMode(pin_LED, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(pin_LED, LOW);
}

const int nmeas = 256; //measurements to take
long int sumsum = 0; //running sum of 64 sums
long int skip = 0; //number of skipped sums
long int diff = 0;      //difference between sum and avgsum
long int flash_period = 0; //period (in ms)
long unsigned int prev_flash = 0; //time stamp of previous flash

void loop() {



  int minval = 2000;
  int maxval = 0;

  //perform measurement
  long unsigned int sum = 0;
  for (int imeas = 0; imeas < nmeas + 2; imeas++) {
    //reset the capacitor
    pinMode(pin_cap, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(pin_cap, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(20);
    pinMode(pin_cap, INPUT);
    //apply pulses
    for (int ipulse = 0; ipulse < npulse; ipulse++) {
      digitalWrite(pin_pulse, HIGH); //takes 3.5 microseconds
      delayMicroseconds(3);
      digitalWrite(pin_pulse, LOW); //takes 3.5 microseconds
      delayMicroseconds(3);
    }
    //read the charge on the capacitor
    int val = analogRead(pin_cap); //takes 13x8=104 microseconds
    minval = min(val, minval);
    maxval = max(val, maxval);
    sum += val;

    //determine if LEDs should be on or off
    long unsigned int timestamp = millis();
    byte ledstat = 0;
    if (timestamp < prev_flash + 12) {
      if (diff > 0)ledstat = 1;
      if (diff < 0)ledstat = 2;
    }
    if (timestamp > prev_flash + flash_period) {
      if (diff > 0)ledstat = 1;
      if (diff < 0)ledstat = 2;
      prev_flash = timestamp;
    }
    if (flash_period > 1000)ledstat = 0;

    //switch the LEDs to this setting
    if (ledstat == 0) {
      digitalWrite(pin_LED, LOW);
    }
    if (ledstat == 1) {
      digitalWrite(pin_LED, LOW);
    }
    if (ledstat == 2) {
      digitalWrite(pin_LED, HIGH);
    }

    if (pin_LED, LOW) {
      servo1.write(0);
      delay(1000);
    }

    if (pin_LED, HIGH) {
      servo1.write(90);
      delay(1000);
    }

  }

  //subtract minimum and maximum value to remove spikes
  sum -= minval; sum -= maxval;

  //process
  if (sumsum == 0) sumsum = sum << 6; //set sumsum to expected value
  long int avgsum = (sumsum + 32) >> 6;
  diff = sum - avgsum;
  if (abs(diff)<avgsum >> 10) {   //adjust for small changes
    sumsum = sumsum + sum - avgsum;
    skip = 0;
  } else {
    skip++;
  }
  if (skip > 64) {  // break off in case of prolonged skipping
    sumsum = sum << 6;
    skip = 0;
  }

  // one permille change = 2 ticks/s
  if (diff == 0) flash_period = 1000000;
  else flash_period = avgsum / (2 * abs(diff));
}
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to post the actual code you wrote that isn't working so we can help. Have you read the Arduino Servo tutorials? Controlling a servo isn't the same as turning a LED on and off.

https://docs.arduino.cc/learn/electronics/servo-motors

Comment: i've added the code now and the thing is im not sure how the original code works as well which is why i dont know what to alter to make this work

Comment: Sorry, we can help you find and fix an error or help you solve a problem but you've got to learn the basics on your own.